# BASH Nested Process Substitution

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, named-pipes, process-substitution

I'm trying to use the stdout of a process substitution in a while loop like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_1=f1.txt
FILE_2=f2.txt

while read LINE; do
    echo "$LINE"
done < <(paste <(tail -f "$FILE_1") <(tail -f "$FILE_2"))
```

What it's supposed to do is merge the last lines of FILE_1 and FILE_2 whenever new data is added to the files. Obviously, I want to do more than just print the line in the while loop, but this is a good example.

Unfortunately, when I run this script, it just sits at the terminal and does nothing.

Running just this line:

```
paste <(tail -f "$FILE_1") <(tail -f "$FILE_2")
```

works perfectly, and I can see the output on the terminal as I add in data to the files.

Is there some special syntax I need to use in order to pipe the stdout to another process?

I've tried doing

```
paste <(tail -f "$FILE_1") <(tail -f "$FILE_2") | while read LINE; do...
```

but it still just sits at the terminal.

Comment: @Kashyap No, I'm trying to do process substitution with a redirection. I'm not sure what << (...) even does.

Comment: @Kashyap: I cannot find any information on using an << operator. Can you link me to the relevant section of the manpage?

Comment: @kashyap is mixing up here documents but that's completely a red herring here. Removing this comment thread would be a good way forward.

Comment: Sounds like buffering to me. Have you checked that it's not just waiting until you've appended a sufficient number of lines to your files?

Comment: @thatotherguy: What exactly would be buffering? It should be reading from the pipe as data comes in right? I believe that the read is unblocked as soon as data is available. And just the paste command with the two process substitutions as inputs works fine, so how do I just get that stdout stream?

Comment: libc buffers stdout when it's not a terminal. You can see this effect by appending `| cat` to your working command, and noticing how it too appears to hang, even though it should be identical. Try `stdbuf -oL paste <(tail -f "$FILE_1") <(tail -f "$FILE_2") | while read ...` if you're on a GNU system

Comment: @thatotherguy: Thank you, that worked perfectly. If you submit that as an answer, I'll mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When stdout is not a terminal, `paste` will buffer its output. Your command works, it just requires a certain amount of input before anything happens.

To get output immediately, you can unbuffer stdout with `stdbuf`:

```
stdbuf -oL paste <(tail -f "$FILE_1") <(tail -f "$FILE_2") | while read LINE; do...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 primary problems. The first being you need to combine the use of a **here string**, **command substitution**, along with **process substitution** to accomplish the redirection you desire. For example:

```
while read LINE
do 
    echo "$LINE"
done <<< "$( paste <( tail -2 "$FILE_1" ) <( tail -2 "$FILE_1" ) )"
```

The command above works fine. However, **note** that the commands above use a determinable set of lines from `FILE_1` and `FILE_2` by using a closed form of `tail` (e.g. `tail -2`). I do not think you can use the `follow` option in this situation. I'm looking, but have not found the rule why yet. Using the `--serial` option to paste makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into using the a combination of those elements. Can you explain why the process substitution I tried doesn't work? Just the paste command with the two process substitutions as inputs works fine, so how do I just get that stdout stream?